# How to lazy load while obeying Law of Demeter?

Tags: c++, law-of-demeter

I would like to obey Law of Demeter. But I would also like to lazy load some objects passed to constructors. How should I implement that? Pass a wrapper class? Pass a function pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually write a generic wrapper that accomplish this:

```
template <typename T>
class Lazy {
public:
  explicit Lazy(T const& t): _loader(), _item(t) {}
  explicit Lazy(T&& t): _loader() _item(t) {}
  explicit Lazy(std::function<T()> l): _loader(l), _item() {}

  T& operator*() { return this->get(); }
  T const& operator*() const { return this->get(); }

  T* operator->() { return &this->get(); }
  T const* operator->() const { return &this->get(); }

private:
  T& get() { if (not _item) { _item = _loader(); } return *_item; }
  T const& get() const { if (not _item) { _item = _loader(); } return *_item; }

  std::function<T()> _loader;
  mutable boost::optional<T> _item;
}; // class Lazy
```

This class guarantees that the loader is executed once, as long as it completes. If it does not complete, then execution will be retried on the next access. It is not thread-safe.

Usage:

```
// Output prime numbers as text
bool isPrime(int);
std::string toEnglish(int);

void print(int i, Lazy<std::string> const& heavy) {
    if (not isPrime(i)) { return; }

    std::cout << *heavy << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) { return 1; }

    int max = atoi(argv[1]);
    for (int i = 2; i <= max; ++i) {
        print(i, [=](){ return toEnglish(i); });
              // ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ C++11 lambda syntax
    }
}
```

Here, `toEnglish` is only ever invoked for prime numbers.

Comment: Thanks, can you provide an example on how to use this? I can compile it but have no clue on how to use.

Comment: `get()` is private, so you can't just use it in `print`. :) I moved the `private:` down two lines, since I think that is what you actually intended. Revert if not. I also changed the lambda, since you need to actually catch `i`.

Comment: @Xeo: I reverted your changes. Indeed `get` is internal, I changed `print` to use `*` instead. Regarded the lambda, I thought that by default the capture would occur by value so one did not have to specify the `&` (capturing an `int` by reference is somewhat wasteful).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: If you don't specify any capture default (or explicit captures), nothing will get captured and the compiler will error out. Since you want to copy, you need `[=]`.